# Soldering substitute

Tags: soldering

I am actually working on a project and I have to solder the LCD16x2 to an I²C Interface and I don't have a soldering iron. Isn't there any other solutions to attach my I²C to the LCD with a proper electrical connection?

Comment: Your frustration dealing with this will be greater than the hassle of buying a cheap soldering iron and learning to solder. If you intend to do electronics for more than 5 or 10 mins in your life, definitively do the effort of soldering it.

Comment: But well, its technically viable, if you are desperate or just want to see it work, go for it.

Comment: @gnimmargorP  Any other ideas ??? I don't really have a soldering iron !!! 

Comment: Idea 1 was buying one, idea 2 is borrowing one, idea 3 is going to a place where you can use one. :) More ideas, idk, change hobby?

Comment: Off the shelf sticky tape is probably not the answer, but the *proper* way of solving this may not be solder either - no one can tell you without specific details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: What kind of specific details you need ??????

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's kind of ridiculous

Comment: Use needlenose pliers to bend the header pins just slightly out of alignment, before inserting them into the holes. Alternate between left / right / left / right, and only bend the pins enough for friction to grab hold. This won't work if you try bending the pins after inserting them in the hole: you have to bend each pin just beyond where the hole wants to be, to ensure a snug fit. And provide mechnaical strain relief to prevent the wires from pulling on the header. There must be slack in the wires or else the connections will be too unreliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No. Definitely not.

Sure, you might get *some* contact between the pin headers, but it will be ***extremely*** unreliable. It's like trying to patch a leak in a boat with duck tape: sure, it might cover the hole, but it will definitely not be very reliable, as water will still be leaking through the seams. Always try to find the right tool for the job. In your case, that would be a soldering iron and some solder, or you could try cold soldering.

Comment: Can you say where can I get a cheap and nice quality soldering iron ?????

Comment: @SagnikPeadhan Radioshack.com would be a good start.

Comment: Or any place that sells chinese products

Comment: You can get them anywhere from amazon to ebay !!!!!!!!!!!